# Get zip codes in a 25 mile radius Android

Tags: java, android, reverse-geocoding

Does android have the ability to receive a zip code from an edit text box and then get the zip codes in a 25 (or whatever) radius to use in my query?

Comment: if you can use internet .. definitely yes..
you can use google map apis.. 
Natively from android seems not possible..

Comment: check out **android.location.Geocoder**.

Comment: Thank you both for the advice and a good starting point. 2 x +1

Answer (score 0):

Here is a web service that wil satisfy ur needs : [very useful](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html)